# ASP.NET API Postgresql TimeoutException NpgsqlConnector GetPooledConnector

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, iis-7, application-pool

We have an ASP.net API using postgres, usually everything works fine, but from time to time we have this exception:

> ```
> Exception information: 
> Exception type: TimeoutException 
> Exception message: Dns hostname lookup timeout. Increase Timeout value in ConnectionString.    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(Int32 timeout)    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open()    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)    at  Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NpgsqlConnection connection)    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
> ```

At first I thought it could be related to the connection pool, so added some code to check on open vs closed connections (we have MAXPOOL set at 100).

For every webapp querying the api I found 2 connections remain open, but no queries are related, if I recycle the application pool problem goes away as connections reset.

¿Any ideas on how can I identity the leaked connections?

Comment: Any hard evidence that issue is *not* related to what error reports (i.e. that it's not a pure network issue)?

Comment: yes it works just fine most of the time, but when reaching 100+ (the maxpool of connections) it stops responding